# Handling Multiple Data Dependencies in Controllers

Tags: c#, algorithm, solid-principles

I am looking for a proper way to handle data dependencies from where, for example if a `purchase(s)` is made the `loading order` should be created based on the purchase(s). Code for Purchases:

```
public partial class Purchase
 {
   public int PurchaseId { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
   public decimal? Payment { get; set; }
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }
   public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
   public int? SalesmanId { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public string User { get; set; }
 }
```

and my loading order:

```
public partial class LoadingOrder
 {
   public int Id {get; set; }
   public int? SalesmanId { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public int LoadedQuantity { get; set; }
   public int? ReturnedQuantity { get; set; }
   public DateTime LoadingDay { get; set; }
   public string User { get; set; }
 }
```

they have related data I use the `purchase` data to fill the `loadingOrder` then I save it; all of this in the `PurchaseController` in the `POST` Method , clearly I am violating the `SOLID Principles`. My question arises from this. is there a better way (pattern)?

Answer (score 1):

I don`t like to keep any logic or operation inside the controller. For me the controller is responsible to send data tp the view and receive data from the view.

I`d create a class responsible for manipulating the Purchase and another class responsible for manipulating the LoadingOrder. Your controller can use these classes. In this case you remove the responsibility of the controller.

Comment: so are these classes ```Repositories``` or ```Services``` ?

Comment: If you have only CRUD operations it is a repository.

Comment: If may ask you'll have these repositories handling Controllers logic,  if the data dependency is still tightly coupled, how do you break it (a layer of abstraction)?

Comment: How about testing?

Comment: In my opinion it becomes easier, you can create specific test for the classes and methods, better than test all your action in the controller.

Comment: I presume you create two types of repositories for Controllers and for the EF?